# limit text input to match HH:MM format with max hours and resetting to previous value if entered wrong

Tags: javascript

I want to limit value/numbers inside a text input to match the HH:MM format, possibly also limit max hrs input (i.e. max 8) while also preventing any other input format in that field. Ideally would be if a number is entered to high, instead of resetting the field/number set it back to the previous number that was already contained or selected via the range slider (not simply clearing it).

**Would I have to extract the first, second, fourth & fifth number from that text field and check them individually or any other approach I could use?**

The only other alternative I can think of is using *two separate text input fields* and display a static colon symbol between them, checking each individually (but entry field may look neater where only hrs and mins are changeable) i.e.

```
document.getElementById('hrs').addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    this.value = (parseInt(this.value) < 0 || parseInt(this.value) > 8 || isNaN(this.value)) ? "00" : (this.value)
});
document.getElementById('mins').addEventListener('keyup', function(){
        this.value = (parseInt(this.value) < 0 || parseInt(this.value) > 8 || isNaN(this.value)) ? "00" : (this.value)
    });
//still requires a reset to previous value instead of fixed "00"
//I also tried this with just one field but no idea how to target just the first and last double digits separately while ignoring the colon symbol.
```

Here is my HH:MM range slider with synced text input field to allow for either input (I haven't found yet any better alternative to this).

HTML

```
 <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="text" id="durationtimestamp" value="00:00" oninput="durationtimestamp(this.value)" required="required">
  
  <input type="range" min="0" max="480" value="0" class="durationslider" id="durationrange" oninput="durationslider(this.value)">
</div>
```

JS

```
function durationslider(value) {

var hours = Math.floor(value / 60).toLocaleString('en-US', {
    minimumIntegerDigits: 2,
    //useGrouping: false
  });
  
var minutes = (value % 60).toLocaleString('en-US', {
    minimumIntegerDigits: 2,
    //useGrouping: false
  });

duration = hours+':'+minutes;
document.getElementById("durationtimestamp").value = duration;

}

function durationtimestamp(value) {

var hours = Math.floor(value / 60).toLocaleString('en-US', {
    minimumIntegerDigits: 2,
    //useGrouping: false
  });
  
var minutes = (value % 60).toLocaleString('en-US', {
    minimumIntegerDigits: 2,
    //useGrouping: false
  });

var myduration = moment.duration(value).asMinutes().toString();
var current = document.getElementById("durationrange").value;
document.getElementById("durationrange").value = myduration;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/markusd1984/u3gfod5x/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the input with js like this

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");

const checkingInput = (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.value.length <= 5);
    if(!/0[0-8]:[0-5][0-9]$/.test(event.target.value)){
    input.value = null;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onchange="checkingInput(event)"/>
```

it should work

Comment: Thanks, however it's clearing the field instead of keeping previous input, note second digit can only go up to 0-5 as there are no more than 59 seconds in a minute. =) I managed to adopt yours and make it work by storing the input innerHTML into a temp previnput var which i keep updating at event change and otherwise use when input was wrong (mismatched the regex). Feel free to adjust and I'll accept your answer, cheers. 

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/markusd1984/2t3mn605/30/

Comment: and a '$' missing at end of regex to prevent more data entry. https://jsfiddle.net/markusd1984/2t3mn605/37/

Comment: I created my regex here. I maybe didn't fully understand what you really want, but I am really glad that I could help a little. if you need to create new  regex and an env to test it this site will help a lot : https://www.regextester.com/107511.

Comment: can you pls update the regex in your code so I can accept your answer, want to make sure it makes sense in this context for others to use, cheers. `/0[0-8]:[0-5][0-9]$/`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) attribute or a `<datalist>`.

Although you didn't mention them a `<select>` or some radio buttons could also be used.

```js
const error = document.getElementById("error");

document.getElementById("frm").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  const valid = this.checkValidity();
  error.classList.toggle("hidden", valid);
  if (!valid) {
    const value = this.getAttribute("value");
    this.value = value;
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span id="error" class="error hidden">Error</span>

<form id="frm">

  <label for="time">Time</label>
  <input type="text" id="time" pattern="[0]?[0-8]:[0-5][0-9]" placeholder="HH:MM" value="1:00" required>
  <br>

  <label for="duration">Time</label>
  <input list="duration-options" id="duration" pattern="[0]?[0-8]:[0-5][0-9]" placeholder="HH:MM" value="1:00" required>
  <datalist id="duration-options">
<option>0:30</option>
<option>1:00</option>
<option>4:00</option>
<option>8:00</option>
</datalist>
  <br>

  <label for="times">Time</label>
  <select id="times">
    <option>0:30</option>
    <option>1:00</option>
    <option>4:00</option>
    <option>8:00</option>
  </select>

  <p>Time</p>
  <label><input type="radio" name="time" value="0:30">0:30</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="time" value="1:00">1:00</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="time" value="4:00">4:00</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="time" value="8:00">8:00</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, for individual HH:MM entry I don't think fixed answers are as easy as a text field or slider, hence I used the combination of both for quick selection vs simple manual entry see https://jsfiddle.net/markusd1984/2t3mn605/37 . Good to know about <pattern>. I wanted to reset to previous value rather than blank or error message, which I think i more user friendly. I must compliment though using addEventListener over inline event handler, which I only now found out is not recommended anymore and doesn't work in my chrome extension thus need to adjust it. Will revert back.

Comment: `this.value = value;` reverts to the value the page loaded with